# Quasar Table Editing with body slot

Tags: javascript, vue.js, quasar-framework

I'm trying to use the q-table selection property with the body slot. Like following

```
 <q-table
        style="max-height: calc(100vh - 48px)"
        ref="table"
        :title="$t('live-sub')"
        :data="data"
        :table-colspan="1"
        :loading="loading"
        row-key="index"
        :filter="filter"
        virtual-scroll
        virtual-scroll-slice-size="15"
        virtual-scroll-item-size="65"
        :pagination="pagination"
        :rows-per-page-options="[0]"
        @virtual-scroll="onScroll"
        hide-header
        hide-bottom
        selection="multiple"
        v-model="selectedLessons"
      >
    <template v-slot:body="props">
          <q-tr :props="props" :key="`m_${props.row.index}`">
            <q-td style="padding: 0">
              <q-item
                :key="props.row.index"
                dense
                :class="{
                  'bg-black text-white selected':
                    props.row.index === liveSubState.currSub,
                  'q-pa-none': true,
                }"
              >
                <q-item-section>
                  <LiveSubtitleRow
                    ref="pageLiveSubtitles"
                    :subtitle="props.row"
                    :rowId="'sub-' + props.row.index"
                    :id="'sub-' + props.row.index"
                    :isSelected="props.row.index === liveSubState.currSub"
                    :subtitles="subtitles"
                  />
                </q-item-section>
              </q-item>
            </q-td>
          </q-tr>
        </template>
    </q-table>
```

I could not see any checkboxes (I think because of body slot I used). I tried the following inside body slot and was able to see to checkboxes but I was unable to check/uncheck them and get the selected row.

```
 <q-td class="checkbox-td">
          <q-checkbox v-model="props.selectedLessons" color="primary" />
        </q-td>
```

I want my user to be able to select/unselect rows in table and get the selected rows inside selectedLessons array. Kindly help